# Page numbering format

Tags: page-numbering

I would like to use the formatting of the page numbering to get the appearance as the attached pictures show. I want to use it for all pages with the exception of the first page where is the page number(1) already hidden. Is there any easy way how to do that?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a page style set for the first page, or perhaps are using `\thispagestyle{empty}`. For the rest, you can easily use [`tikz`](//ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for the decoration and [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) for the placement:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \tikz \node [circle, fill = black!30] {\textcolor{white}{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}};}

\pagestyle{fancy}% Set the page style to fancy

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is working well! The only thing I had to fix yet was it didn't affect the TableOfContent page (2. page in my case) so I used this there: \tableofcontents \thispagestyle{fancy} and that's it. Thank you @Werner.